# SocketException: socket closed in accept() on ServerSocket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, port

I had written a small code where I am trying to listen on particular port as follows (just trying out something) :

```
public class Test {

    public static class MyThread extends Thread {
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        public MyThread(int port){
            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in assigning port : " + port);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void stopListening(){
            try {
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in closing socket : " + ss.getLocalPort());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void run(){
            try {
                ss.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in listening on port : " + ss.getLocalPort());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyThread> threadList = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 50000; i < 50005; i++) {
            MyThread thread = new MyThread(i);
            threadList.add(thread);
            thread.start();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (MyThread myThread : threadList) {
            myThread.stopListening();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am unable to start even a single thread , for every `ss.accept()` I keep getting :

> Exception in listening on port :

I get the following exception in each case :

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.harman.hlacssmdw.Test$MyThread.run(Test.java:40)
```

I checked the ports from 50000 to 50000 using netstat -anp , none of theme are occupied.

I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong, Please help !!!

Comment: You get the exception about 5 seconds after you start the program? Right about the time you call stopListening() ?

Comment: yes I get this after about 5 seconds , but at the line 'ss.accept()'

Comment: It throws an exception because you are calling `accept()` at the same as you are closing the socket. What exactly did you expect to happen? And why are you calling `accept()` and ignoring the return value? And there is no 'unable to listen' here. Unclear what you're asking, and what your code is supposed to do that it isn't already doing.

Answer (score 4):

The ServerSocket is closed because you close it by calling stopListening(). That leads to an Exception for all Threads waiting on accept() of that ServerSocket.

Comment: And the fact that this happens 5 seconds after the application starts is supporting evidence for this.  Because he waits 5 seconds before calling `stopListening()` on the threads.

Comment: thanks a lott, but can you please also explain why closing the socket throws an exception , and also why it causes ss.accept() to throw an exception ?? that would be really helpful

Comment: @FurquanAhmed It throws an exception because you closed the socket while continuing to use it, and the reason why it causes `accept()` to throw an exception is the same. Hard to see why you're surprised.